# Custom BaseAdapter only adds Last Element to ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I designed a custom BaseAdapter that Takes an ArrayList of a Class(JsonKeys) which contains getters and setters for the data i need.

I'm basically parsing a JSON Array and inserting the appropriate data into listrows which is given below:

```
"attendanceData": [
    {
      "ccode": "MAT 212",
      "cname": "ENGINEERING MATHEMATICS- IV",
      "cclass": "30",
      "bunked": "5",
      "percent": "86",
      "updated": "3\/20\/13"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "CSE 202",
      "cname": "FORMAL LANGUAGES &amp; AUTOMATA THEORY",
      "cclass": "28",
      "bunked": "3",
      "percent": "91",
      "updated": "3\/15\/13"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "CSE 204",
      "cname": "RELATIONAL DATABASE MANAGEMENT SYSTEMS",
      "cclass": "24",
      "bunked": "2",
      "percent": "93",
      "updated": "3\/15\/13"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "CSE 206",
      "cname": "MICROPROCESSORS",
      "cclass": "30",
      "bunked": "1",
      "percent": "97",
      "updated": "3\/6\/13"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "CSE 208",
      "cname": "EVENT DRIVEN PROGRAMMING USING JAVA",
      "cclass": "32",
      "bunked": "2",
      "percent": "95",
      "updated": "3\/14\/13"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "OPE 1",
      "cname": "OPEN ELECTIVE - ADVERTISING THEORY &amp; PRACTICE&nbsp;&#40;PME 332&#41;",
      "cclass": "13",
      "bunked": "3",
      "percent": "82",
      "updated": "3\/21\/13"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "CSE 210",
      "cname": "MICROPROCESSORS LAB",
      "cclass": "NA",
      "bunked": "NA",
      "percent": "NA",
      "updated": "NA"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "CSE 212",
      "cname": "JAVA PROGRAMMING LAB",
      "cclass": "NA",
      "bunked": "NA",
      "percent": "NA",
      "updated": "NA"
    },
    {
      "ccode": "CSE 214",
      "cname": "RELATIONAL DATABASE MANAGEMENT SYSTEMS LAB",
      "cclass": "NA",
      "bunked": "NA",
      "percent": "NA",
      "updated": "NA"
    }
  ]
```

And these are my classes for Custom BaseAdapter and the Fragment which inflates the listview, respectively.

```
public class AttendanceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private ArrayList<JsonKeys> adapterkeylist = new ArrayList<JsonKeys>();
    private Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    TextView subject, code, attended, absent, percent, updated;
    JsonKeys dataString = new JsonKeys();

    public AttendanceListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<JsonKeys> jk)
    {
        context = c;
        adapterkeylist =jk;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return adapterkeylist.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {

        // return s[s.length/6][s.length%6];
        return adapterkeylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;


        if (convertView == null)
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_listrow, null);

        subject = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subName);
        subject.setSelected(true);
        code = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ccode);
        attended = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subAttended);
        absent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subAbsent);
        percent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subPercent);
        updated = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subUpdated);


        dataString = adapterkeylist.get(position);

        Log.i("Info Tag Attendance","\n"+dataString.getName());

        subject.setText(dataString.getName());
        code.setText("Subject Code: " + dataString.getCode());
        attended.setText("Classes Attended: " + dataString.getCClass());
        absent.setText("Classes Absent: " + dataString.getBunked());
        percent.setText("Attendance Percentage: " + dataString.getPercent());
        updated.setText("Last Updated: " + dataString.getUpdated());

        return v;

    }

}
```

The Fragment:

```
public class AttendanceDetailsTabFragment extends Fragment
{
    AttendanceListAdapter adapter;
    JSONArray ar;
    JSONObject jobj;
    ArrayList<JsonKeys> keyslist;
    JsonKeys jk;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_listview_layout, container, false);

        keyslist = new ArrayList<JsonKeys>();
        String temp = new String();

        try
        {
            ar = new JSONArray();
            ar = GlobalVars.getJSON().getJSONArray("attendanceData");

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++)
            {

                JSONObject jObject = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                jk = new JsonKeys();
                jk.setCode(jObject.getString("ccode"));
                temp = jObject.getString("cname");
                temp = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(temp);// To convert HTML
                                                                // special chars
                                                                // to UniCode
                                                                // format;
                jk.setName(temp);
                jk.setCClass(jObject.getString("cclass"));
                jk.setBunked(jObject.getString("bunked"));
                jk.setPercent(jObject.getString("percent"));
                jk.setUpdated(jObject.getString("updated"));
                Log.i("Info Tag Attendance",
                        jk.getCode() + "\n" + jk.getName() + "\n" + jk.getCClass() + "\n" + jk.getBunked() + "\n" + jk.getPercent() + "\n"
                                + jk.getUpdated() + "\n");

                keyslist.add(jk);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("Error Tag", "Could Not Get JSON Array");
        } finally
        {
            Log.i("Info Tag Attendance", "\n" + keyslist.size());

        }

        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);

        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        adapter = new AttendanceListAdapter(getActivity(), keyslist);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (container == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

A screenshot of what's happening can be found at http://postimg.org/image/6qs3oo3hp/

As you can see only the last element is being entered into the ListView.
Any fixes would be welcome.
I apolgize for the code length in advance.

Comment: what is `JsonKeys` and `GlobalVars`?

Comment: keyslist have you checked the size of the list ?

Comment: JsonKeys is a global class having setters and getters, and GlobalVars is where I've stored the downloaded JSON data etc..

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,I just realised im setting variables in a Global Class(and not an array), so obviously only the last entered data is recorded(Facepalm).

Stupid mistake,will remake code using HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in android,

I realised that I set the variables of listitemclass as static so it always refers to same variable when view is returned from its adapter.

Removed the static part and it worked ok